# Meaning of はぜ in this context

Tags: translation

These are some lyrics to a song:

> 陽炎ゆらめいて
>
> 追憶の彼方に見た
>
> うたかたの夢はぜ
>
> 火の粉は大空へ舞う

And this is supposed to be the translation:

> After heat haze flickers.
>
> It was seen in the other side of the reminiscence.
>
> Transient dream explosion.
>
> A spark is danced to the sky.

I'm having trouble with the third line, specifically with 「はぜ」. The dictionary translates it as gobby (fish)/wax tree/drying rice on a rack, and obviously none of these make any sense given the context of the song as well as the suggested translation. Outside of these meanings and the song itself, I couldn't find any reference to 「はぜ」 at all. Could it be just a typo, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the translation offered your own or someone else's and if so what language was it originally in?

Comment: The translation was provided by an anonymous person in the comments to the song, ostensibly a native Japanese speaker. It was originally in English, but they are not fluent. I left the translation as-is in hopes of it making some sense to other native speakers. It's the only translation I could find, and the rest of the song was translated pretty well so I thought it would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is no typo; It is an existing verb.

「はぜ」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the verb 「はぜる」, which means ***"to pop", "to burst open"***, etc.

When corn kernels はぜる, it is called "popcorn".

So, the line means:

"***The fleeting dream bursts open (and)***"

A similar-sounding synonym of 「はぜる」 is 「はじける」, which you might actually see/hear more often.  Both are originally Japanese words as, I hope, you can tell from the sounds.

In case you are more of a fan of big Sino-loanwords, 「破裂{はれつ}する」 would be a synonym as well.